# how to know if the input from a text file is a valid numeric in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am new to C++ here, so even though this seems to be a simple question, I still couldn't figure out how to solve it.
So I have a text file, which contains a bunch of numerics. Some are not valid numeric which could be 3.12ad, t3, etc. when I use the following code, it couldn't differentiate whether it reads a bad numeric, or it simply finish reading the file (both situation would give me an error message). So my question is, how can I just capture the bad numeric situation? Thank you.

```
int main() {
string line;
int numOfLine = 0;
int inputNum = 0;
float num;
vector<float> arr1;
vector<float> arr2;
ifstream infile11("test.txt");
while (true) {
        if (infile11 >> num) {
            arr1.push_back(num);
            inputNum ++;
            cout<<num<<endl;
        }
        if ((infile11 >> num).fail()) {
            cout<<"Error"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want `3.12ad` to be treated as the numeral `3.12` followed by text `ad`, or do you want to treat it as invalid?

Comment: You can use `infile1.eof()` to check if end of file has been encountered. Check that when an input operation attempt fails.

Comment: Integers or floating point?  Are you allowing scientific notation, e.g. 3.14E-6?

Comment: If you have a formatting error, `infile11.fail()` will be `true`. If you hit the end of file, `infile11.fali()`  *and* `infile11.eof()` will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to check if the string you get is a number. If i remember right, in C++ it is in #include < regex > . So that you can use regex_match() function. Your regular expression could be something like this: "?\d*(.\d+)?".

Answer (score 0):

you may use standard conversion function (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). If the conversion is not allowed an exception will be raised. Here an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> numbers {"3.14", "10", "t3", "toto"};
    for (auto& nb : numbers)
    {
        bool correct = true;
        for (auto& c : nb)
        {
            try
            {
                std::stof(std::string(&c));
            }
            catch(const std::exception&)
            {
                correct = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!correct)
        {
            std::cout << "Cannnot convert [" << nb << "]\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Correct conversion [" << nb << "]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more detail about what counts as a valid numeric value.  However, making some assumptions there (such as no commas, fractions like 1/2, nor scientific notation), one simple algorithm you can use beyond the regex or conversion attempts suggested in other answers is:

```
For each line until EOF [end of file]
   While current character is whitespace
       advance pointer to next character
   if currentCharacter = '-'
       advance pointer to next character
   decimalEncountered = false
   For each character
       if character >= 0 and character <= 9
            advance pointer to next character
       else if character == '.'
            if (decimalEncountered)
                 exit loop reporting invalid numeric
            else 
                 decimalEncountered = true
       else if character == EOF [end of file]
            exit loop; no invalid numerics encountered
       else if character == line break
            go to next iteration of outer loop
       else
            exit loop reporting invalid numeric
```

I've only provided pseudocode to leave specific implementation as the homework exercise the problem appears to be; hopefully this is a helpful pointer in a useful direction!